# What kind of triangle is triangle ABC?

Tags: geometry

For reference:
In a triangle ABC the medians AM and CN are drawn up that are intersected in “G” such that, the quadrilateral BMGN is circumscribed.
What kind of triangle is triangle ABC?

My progress:
[image]

My progress:

$BM + NG = BN + MG\\
\frac{a}{2}+\frac{CN}{3} = \frac{c}{2}+\frac{AM}{3}\\
\frac{a-c}{2} = \frac{AM-CN}{3}$

could someone demonstrate the solution?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "quadrilateral is circumscribed"? (Looking at your work, it suggests that we can inscribe a circle.)

Comment: @CalvinLin..Correct ....The correct term would be quadrilateral circumscribing..forgive me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using standard notation for side lengths and writing $m_a$ for $AM$ and $m_c$ for $CN$.

Given $BMGN$ is tangential quadrilateral,

$BN + MG = BM + NG$

$\frac{c}{2} + \frac{m_a}{3} = \frac{a}{2} + \frac{m_c}{3}$

$m_a - m_c = \frac{3}{2} (a-c) \tag1$

Now we note that the circle inscribed in $BMGN$ is also the incircle of $\triangle ABM$ and $\triangle CBN$. As, the area of both triangles is same and their inradius is equal, their perimeter must be equal too.

So, $m_a + c + \frac{a}{2} = m_c + a + \frac{c}{2}$

$ \implies m_a - m_c = \frac12 (a-c)$

From $(1)$,

$\frac32 (a-c) = \frac12 (a-c)$

$a - c = 0 \implies a = c$.

Comment: Hi...I think that there is a problem in the statement because the answer would be isosceles but you were able to demonstrate it in a scalene triangle...thankful

Comment: $BM + NG = BN + MG\\
\frac{a}{2}+\frac{CN}{3} = \frac{c}{2}+\frac{AM}{3}\\
\frac{a-c}{2} = \frac{AM-CN}{3}\\
mas ~AM = CN \therefore \frac{a-c}{2} = \frac{0}{3}\\
\therefore a = c \implies \boxed{\color{red}triangulo~ isosceles}$ what's wrong with this demo?

Comment: Pitot theorem..states that in a tangential quadrilateral (i.e. one in which a circle can be inscribed) the two sums of lengths of opposite sides are the same

Comment: but the statement says that the quadrilateral is circumscribed and not inscribed

Comment: don't worry...for a moment I thought I was confused...

Comment: I think the English term is correct....circumscribed quadrilateral mean a circle inscribed into a quadrilateral?...or is there another term?

Comment: yes I am not sure when I read but I somehow remember reading it differently. It may have been just my confusion. Let me know if you have any questions on the revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What is the formula for median lengths by Stewarts theorem?

> $$ m_a = \frac{\sqrt{ 2b^2+2c^2 - a^2 }} { 2 } $$

**Corollary:** OP's last equation is true iff $ a = c$.
(That this is an equality case should be obvious by symmetry. It remains to show that this is the only case.)

> Show that if $ a > c $, then
>  $$ LHS = \frac{a-c}{2} > 0 > \frac {\sqrt{ 2b^2+2c^2-a^2 } - \sqrt{ 2b^2+2a^2 - c^2 }}{6} = RHS $$

Comment: I don't understand... who is it LHS? RHS?  I need to demonstrate that AB = BC because the triangle will be isosceles

Comment: @petaarantes Left Hand Side and Right Hand Side (of your last equation).